# Updating two states at the same time puts the component in infinite loop - REACTJS WITH DJANGO BACKEND

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-effect, use-state

I am a beginner at ReactJs and I'm creating an app using ReactJs and Django as backend.

I have created a sign in functionality and the signed-in user's pfp gets displayed in the navbar.

So in my sub-component `ShowNavUser()` I have 2 states: `username` and `userImage`. I make an ajax(Axios) call to the Django backend and once that is done I am updating the `username` and `userImage` states with the data returned.

Here is the code:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState();
const [userImage, setUserImage] = useState();
const url = `http://localhost:8000/users/${props.loggedUser}`;
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setUsername(response.data.username);
        setUserImage(response.data.profile_pic);
    });
});
```

Now as a result of that, I am getting a loop of requests to the backend which is freezing my app.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is going into an infinite loop due to a minor error. Just fix it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setUsername(response.data.username);
        setUserImage(response.data.profile_pic);
    });
}, []); // added this []
```

Comment: that did solve the problem...so thank you very much!! I don't know why I didn't do that before... it was a pretty silly mistake